# Jquery Datatable is not showing all the data when we do vertical scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, datatables

I have declared one table with out data and given the ID. I am calling the web api call getting more than 500 records. I have hard coded set the data and when I am binding the data dynamically to the table and set the `scrollY: "300px"` etc. Now I am able to see the table but when I do vertical scroll then I can not see all the rows.

Please find the below link which has code and help me to fix the issue:

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0hfg7618)</kbd>

Comment: when I ran the code data is missing.

Comment: Hi Talsibony, Please find the jsfiddle link for the code. There you can see the issue

Comment: Hi do you want pagination for datatable or you want whole data table using   vertical scroll.?

Comment: Hi Dipak, I do not want pagination. I want to show all the rows but when user do vertical scrolling the message "Showing 1 to 953 of 953 entries" it should update like "Showing 20 to 30 of 953 entries".

Comment: Here is the link "https://jsfiddle.net/0hfg7618/18/"

Comment: problem in    $('#tblBuyers').next('div').remove(); when it comment it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi small change required put

```
 paging=false;
```

but one more thing when you are using angular then use angular datatable

Read
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

This help you to use angular feature with your datatable

Comment: Hi Pravin,  Thanks for the reply. I have tried with the above answer but the message "Showing 1 to 953 of 953 entries" is not updating based on scroll

Comment: Yes I have checked. below the table we have message like "Showing 1 to 953 of 953 entries". Based on the scroll it should update like "Showing 20 to 30 of 953 entries". For your reference here is the example link "https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html"

Comment: you should need to include required  external file see External Resources in  jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Pravin,  Thanks for the reply. I have found the fix and fixed the issue.